# Qt6 on Raspberry OS - How to install and use PySide6?

Tags: python, qt, raspberry-pi, pyside6

I've been using PyQt5 for developing GUI applications on Raspberry OS.

Now I want to use the recent Qt version 6 for my Raspberry OS.
I've searched a little, but couldn't find an easy solution to install Qt6 and PySide6 on Raspberry OS.

How to install and use Qt6 and PySide6?

Comment: Recommendation: There is nothing new in Qt6 yet (besides that many modules have been deactivated) so the benefit will be much less than the effort (compiling Qt6 is not simple)

Comment: Thank you.
I want Qt6 not for newer features, I just wanted to test and compare its performance on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: My recommendation is that you ask a single question: How to compile Qt6 in Raspberry, and for the moment forget about pyside6, when you achieve the first then if you try the second. On the other hand in general you should use the same manuals that are used to compile Qt5, have you tried something?

Comment: Note: There is no easy way to install Qt6 since you will have to compile it manually since neither the official OS repos nor Qt company provides the binaries for RPi

Comment: I will try to compile it. And once success will deploy the binary to GitHub.
I'll leave more comments if I face to another issue on compiling.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the team of Qt6 works together with Nuitka, so the best way seems to be:

```
pip install nuitka
python -m nuitka --standalone --enable-plugin=pyside6 --show-progress --windows-disable-console --macos-disable-console --include-qt-plugins=all --output-dir=bin --follow-imports --include-data-files=main.qml=main.qml --include-data-dir=res=res main.py
```

And this seems to be the only working transpiler for Qt6. It works for me, but there are dlls galore (>150) to be copied